# Access Report won't allow me to refer to a field in VBA unless it's on the report in its own right

Tags: ms-access, vba

So, in an Access Form or Report a good way to show something dynamic on the screen that is more complex than `=[UnitPrice]*[Quantity]` is to drop into VBA.

e.g. in this simplified example, the underlying table for this Report has two fields **ShowTax** and **TaxRate**. By making a TextBox's control source `=GetTaxInfo` I get to introduce some complexity in VBA:

```
Public Function GetTaxInfo() As String

    Dim result As String
    If Me!ShowTax = 0 Then
        result = "Tax included @ " & Me!TaxRate

    Else
        result = ""
    End If

    GetTaxInfo = result

End Function
```

OK, this works ... so long as I have a field somewhere else that refers to TaxRate. Otherwise it just prints `#Error`. It's as if it needs to *preload* the field before it can be used in VBA code. It isn't the end of the world because I can have a bunch of fields in the report all set to not be visible, but it's untidy.

So is it the case that you can't refer to a field *in VBA code backing a report* unless you have *already referred to the field in the conventional way as a field baked into the report?*

I can't remember encountering this limitation before. Or is it that I have a corrupt report? (I have tried the usual compact/repair, export/reimport the Report etc)

**Edit:**

the weird thing is ... now it's working again. And - I'm pretty sure - there is no control in the report. which is why I was thinking it was a corruption in the report.

Comment: You're encountering what I consider a bug that was introduced into Access in the A2000 time frame. My surmise is that the introduction of support for ADO in Access forms/reports somehow decoupled the Access expression service from its connections to fields in the recordsources of forms/reports, with the results that you see, i.e., a field in the recordsource is not accessible in the form's/report's VBA code unless that field is the ControlSource of a control on the form/report. The problem was very narrow in A2000 but has since expanded. The only solution is a hidden control.

Comment: By the way, I just checked and there's on really important difference between forms and reports: the default "property" of the form object is a union of the Controls and Fields collection (i.e., the controls on the form plust the fields in the recordsource). What I recently discovered was that there isn't really an independent Fields collection, but all the fields in the recordset do show up in the form's Controls collection. For reports, THIS IS NOT THE CASE. The only thing in the default collection of a report is the controls collection and that does not include fields from the recordsource.

Comment: David, your typo .... did you mean "there's no really important" or "there's a really important"?

Comment: I must say that every time I encounter a limitation of Reports compared to Forms, it's hugely frustrating. Their behaviour and capabilities are so similar in many respects that it can really catch you out

Comment: @David - would be happy to mark your above info as the "Accepted Answer" if you wish to move it from Comment to Answer

Comment: Read "there's one really important limitation".

Comment: I think Jeff O's answer predated my comment. Had it not already been there I would have posted an answer.

Comment: @hawbsl – any reason not accept Jeff O's answer?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a control on the form/report.

If this is too messy, you could put the function in a Module and use in the RecordSource (based on a query). No sense burying all this logic in a report when it could be used in other places as well.

```
Public Function GetTaxInfo(ShowTax as Boolean, TaxRate as Single) As String 

    Dim result As String 
    If ShowTax = 0 Then 
        result = "Tax included @ " & TaxRate 

    Else 
        result = "" 
    End If 

    GetTaxInfo = result 

End Function
```

Then the control is set to this field in this report and others.

Comment: You don't need the control on a form, but on a report, event code that refers to controls in the given event needs a control placed on the report to get at the data. Access has always been this way.

Comment: You don't have to use the control though -- all you need is a control on your form that uses the field as its ControlSource. At that point, the field is usable directly in VBA code (i.e., you don't have to use the control's name). I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the implicit property wrappers that VBA creates behind the scenes (i.e., the mechanism that provides compile-time checking of expressions using the dot operator, i.e., Me.MyField).